# How can you return elements between two values?

Tags: elementtype, elementcriteriamodel

I my be in a bit of a "wood for the trees" situation but how is it possible to return elements based on a custom field being between two supplied values.

For example returning users based on a number field. Let's say the number field is between 1 - 100 and I want to return users that have between 5 and 10 selected.

I could do it like the following

```
$users = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User, array("customNumberField"=>array(5,6,7,8,9,10))->find();
```

However that sets `OR`

I know that you can use parameters eg `"customNumberField"=>"<= 10"` but obviously specifying that key twice causes it to be overwritten.

You can also specify an array with the parameters (avoiding the overwriting) like so

```
 $users = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User, array("customNumberField"=>array(">= 5", "<= 10"))->find();
```

But again this just creates `customNumberField >= 5 OR customNumberField <= 10`.

Is it possible to use the array as above but tell it to use `AND` instead of `OR`?

Am I on the right track or way off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re close! You just need to begin the array with `"and"`:

```php
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
$criteria->customNumberField = array('and', '>=5', '<=10');

$users = $criteria->find();
```

This same thing could also be accomplished from your templates like this:

```twig
{% set users = craft.users.customNumberField('and', '>=5', '<=10') %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had even tried it at the end but for some reason didn't try it at the start!

Comment: Brandon, how could/should you write your twig statement in a hash? For example I am using a hash to query the following: `{% set scriptsAboutToExpire = { section: 'scripts', order: 'expirationDate asc', expirationDate: 'and', '>=' ~ now, '<=' ~ now|date_modify('+2 weeks') } %}` but that obviously breaks because of the commas...

Comment: @StevenThate Just wrap the values in a sub-array – `expirationDate: ['and', '>='~now, '<='~now|date_modify('+2 weeks')]`

Comment: @BrandonKelly, how should your answer be expressed in Craft 3? I'm having some difficulty with it :( See: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25825/craft-3-error-variable-now-does-not-exist