# How can I search for entries that are enabled OR disabled?

Tags: plugin-development, search, elementcriteriamodel, models

Within a plugin I am fetching existing entries using the CriteriaModel class as documented here http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements#fetching-elements, specifically like this:

```
$existing = craft()->elements->getCriteria($this->entry->elementType)->first(array(
    'someHandle' => 'someValue'
))
```

However I am finding this only returns a result if an ENABLED entry is found. I can see that I can search for ONE particular enabled state as follows:

```
$existing = craft()->elements->getCriteria($this->entry->elementType)->first(array(
    'someHandle' => 'someValue', 
    'enabled' => 1
))
```

Or...

```
$existing = craft()->elements->getCriteria($this->entry->elementType)->first(array(
    'someHandle' => 'someValue', 
    'enabled' => 0
))
```

But how can I search for ALL entries regardless of the enabled state?

And also, what is the difference between the status and enabled properties on the model? I can see constants for ENABLED, DISABLED and ARCHIVED. I'm not clear on how this differs from the boolean value that the enabled property has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this in php, but on the 'template' side there is an attribute called 'status' which you might try. I assume it would work in php as well.

```
$existing = craft()->elements->getCriteria($this->entry->elementType)->first(array(
    'someHandle' => 'someValue', 
    'status' => null
));
```

Default is 'live'; other values would be 'live', 'pending', 'expired', 'disabled', and null. Here's the docs for [craft.entries.status](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#status). Let us know if it works.

Comment: What Douglas said. There’s actually no `enabled` criteria parameter; only `status`. Setting it to `null` will prevent the elements’ statuses from getting factored into the query.

Comment: Thanks guys. A follow up though - I can see I can use null to get ALL, but if I only want live and pending, how do I do that? In PHP.

Comment: Again, on the backend I'm not 100% sure, but I think that you can simply place all the options in an array like so: `'status' => ['live', 'pending']` or you might also try `'status' => ['and', 'live', 'pending']` or perhaps `'status' => array('and', 'live', 'pending')`.

Comment: If [this answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/how-can-you-return-elements-between-two-values/1683#1683) is any indication it should be the latter `'status' => array('and', 'live', 'pending')`