# Craft 3: Error "variable now does not exist"

Tags: craft3, datetime

I upgraded a Craft 2 project to Craft 3 and am working on updating some template quirks. One I am having trouble with involves the following element query:

```
{% set scriptsAboutToExpire = craft.entries({
    section: 'scripts',
    order: 'expirationDate asc',
    expirationDate: [ 'and', '>=' ~ now, '<=' ~ now|date_modify('+2 weeks') ]
}) %}
```

This worked great in Craft 2. It grabs all `script` entries whose `expirationDate` field is two weeks away from today's date.

However now after upgrading to Craft 3 I am getting the following error when viewing that template:

**PHP Recoverable Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string**

with a highlight on this line:

`(isset($context["now"]) || array_key_exists("now", $context) ? $context["now"] : (function () { throw new Twig_Error_Runtime('Variable "now" does not exist.', 10, $this->source); })())), 2 => ("<=" . twig_date_modify_filter($this->env, (isset($context["now"]) || array_key_exists("now", $context) ? $context["now"] : (function () { throw new Twig_Error_Runtime('Variable "now" does not exist.', 10, $this->source); })()), "+2 weeks"))))), "method");`

I tried updating all `.localeDate()` filters to `|date('short')` but that had no effect.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the `DateTime` object via [Filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#date):

```
 now|date('U')
```

or via function

```
now.format('U')
```

This will format the date as a UNIX timestamp which is sufficient for querying. MySQL datetime format will work too: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

More info can be found in the [upgrade documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/upgrade.html#currency-formatting).

Comment: While it no longer complains that `now` is empty, after modifying `now` in my element query to `'now'|date()`, it still is saying "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string."

`$context["scriptsAboutToExpire"] = array("section" => "scripts", "order" => "expirationDate asc", "expirationDate" => array(0 => "and", 1 => (">=" . $this->extensions['craft\web\twig\Extension']->dateFilter($this->env, "now")), 2 => ("<=" . twig_date_modify_filter($this->env, $this->extensions['craft\web\twig\Extension']->dateFilter($this->env, "now"), "+2 weeks"))));`

Comment: As I said "usually formatted as a timestamp or mysql datetime" it's all stated in the docs and in my answer. You have to convert the DateTime object into a valid sql string format